# Routing Mouse Events through a Sprite in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, sprite, mouseclick-event

In a pure Actionscript 3 project, I have a sprite that overlaps another sprite.  The lower sprite normally handles mouse clicks.  The lower sprite no longer processes mouse events when it is overlapped by the higher sprite.

I understand that this is normal behavior.

I would like the lower sprite to handle mouse events when it is overlapped.  (In my particular instance, the higher sprite is just a decorative piece; it has no normal mouse interactivity anyway.)  Is this possible?  Is there a way to route mouse events through the higher sprite?

I found a short, dated discussion about my problem here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/137/tn_13766.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Should be something like this:

```
higherSprite.mouseEnabled=false;
higherSprite.mouseChildren=false;
```

Comment: You only need to set mouseEnabled.

Comment: If you have other InteractiveObjects (MovieClip, Sprite, etc...) within "higherSprite" you need mouseChildren=false too ;)