# How to make an object be ignored and letting mouse evnets pass through?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

Hallo, I been having this problem for a while and I have no idea how to solve it.

I have a flash game (very much like a normal memory game) that has a lot of Movieclips in it that has MouseEvents attached to them. But, when I add a bitmap over the stage (used for covering lots of unwanted things and has to be there) that is the full size of the screen non of my events are fired anymore. The reason is that the overlay bitmap is stealing all of the events.

How can I stop this behavior? Is there a way of letting the events pass through the overlay object? Or for the overlay object to be ignored when it comes to events?

Thanks.

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187013/routing-mouse-events-through-a-sprite-in-actionscript-3/1187095#1187095

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your overlay is stored in a variable `m_overlay`, then

```
m_overlay.mouseEnabled = false;
```

However you said it is used for "covering lots of unwanted things" so perhaps we need more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this in the past by creating "proxy" object to capture mouse clicks. The MCs under the bitmap aren't going to receive events.